# Hay alguna manera de juntar esta consulta de MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
   $pro1="Tubo Estructural";
   $pro2= "Protector De Corriente";

   $sql= "SELECT producto, SUM(cantidad) as monto FROM grafica WHERE producto = '$pro1' ";
   $query= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

   $sql1= "SELECT producto, SUM(cantidad) as monto FROM grafica WHERE producto = '$pro2'";
   $query1= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);

   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);

       echo $row['producto'].' '.$row['monto'];
        echo $row1['producto'].' '.$row1['monto'];
```

Aclaro eso es lo quiero si me funciona así, pero veo como rendundar información y no creo que sea la manera correcta, hay manera de poder hacer todo eso en una sola consulta ?

Comment: necesitas que encuntre coincidencia con ambos datos de prodcuto o solo con uno?

Comment: si que me encuentre ambos datos de producto y me sume la cantidad. por separado de cada producto un ejemplo : pedro 5 , juan 5, pedro 7, rafael 5: haciendo la consulta llamando a pedro y juan, obteniendo como resultado: pedro 12 y juan 5

Comment: dime si asi te sirve, hacemos uso del `IN` para indicarle que busque registros dentro de esas dos coincidencias, luego le indicamos que las agrupe por nombre del producto por que estamos usando una función de agregación y luego ordenamos los registros por producto `"SELECT producto, SUM(cantidad) as monto 
FROM grafica 
WHERE producto IN('$pro1', '$pro2')
GROUP BY producto
ORDER BY producto";`

Comment: Hermano Correctamente era eso lo que buscaba muchísimas gracias amigo, soy nuevo en esta pagina, la cual creo que trabaja con puntuación como te puntuó

Comment: te la agrego coimo respuesta y la marcas te parece?

Comment: para puntuarla debes dar clic en la palomita que esta a lado de la respuesta @Steban De Abreu

Comment: listo amigo ya lo puntué pasa que tube que salir de emergencia gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hacemos uso del `IN` para indicarle que busque registros dentro de
>   esas dos coincidencias, luego le indicamos que las agrupe por nombre
>   del producto por que estamos usando una función de agregación y luego
>   ordenamos los registros por producto

```
"SELECT producto, SUM(cantidad) as monto 
FROM grafica 
WHERE producto IN('$pro1', '$pro2') 
GROUP BY producto 
ORDER BY producto";
```